# Gravity forms: ACF fields for radio button labels

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am trying to create Gravity forms radio buttons where label is being entered in ACF text fields.

I have tried using Gravity forms [ACF live merge tag](https://docs.gravityforms.com/custom-field-merge-tags/). However, when using merge tag the output comes out like:

```
<label for="choice_16_11_0" id="label_16_11_0">{custom_field:valg_1}</label>
```

The merge tag is just written in plain text and not the actual text from the ACF field. Therefore I figured I had to use [gform_field_choice_markup_pre_render filter](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_field_choice_markup_pre_render/) in order to override the label. I have followed the example found in Gravity forms documentation. My code:

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_choice_markup_pre_render_16_11', function ( $choice_markup, $choice, $field, $value ) {
    if ( $field->get_input_type() == 'radio' ) :

        switch ( rgar( $choice, 'text' ) ) {
            case "Valg 1":
                $description = get_field('valg_1');
                break;
            case "Valg 2":
                $description = get_field('valg_2');
                break;
            case "Valg 3":
                $description = get_field('valg_3');
                break;
        }

    endif;

    return str_replace( "</label>", "</label>$description", $choice_markup );

}, 10, 4 );
```

16 is my form ID and 11 is the field ID for my radio buttons. However, my code doesn't seem to be doing anything. Any pointers on what I might be missing ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking $description out of the quotes inside the return.

FYI if you are trying to replace the choice in its entirety, I would replace the current text value (otherwise your code will simply add a suffix to your existing label).

```
if ( $field->get_input_type() == 'radio' ) :

        switch ( rgar( $choice, 'text' ) ) {
            case "Valg 1":
                $description = get_field('valg_1');
                $current = "Valg 1";
                break;
            case "Valg 2":
                $description = get_field('valg_2');
                $current = "Valg 2";
                break;
            case "Valg 3":
                $description = get_field('valg_3');
                $current = "Valg 3";
                break;
        }

    endif;

    return str_replace( ">".$current, ">".$description, $choice_markup);
```